# Is it possible to change last character in a regex repetition?

Tags: java, regex

I need to include space between each string repetition, that is working fine using `)-- )+`  at the end of the regex, but I need to delete the space for the last string entered.
Using the following regex the space is mandatory for all of the strings including the last one which is not necessary.

How to avoid the space to be mandatory for the last repeated string?

This is my regex:

```
"(?:sv(?:32i|32e)(?:a|m|c|)-(?:32f|32e)(?:a|b|)-- )+"
```

Comment: Something like space or end? `( |$)`

Comment: That's it @JoopEggen, working now, `( |$)` is the correct answer.

Comment: But then I think would still not match the example string from your comment https://regex101.com/r/gy2x9R/1

Answer (score 0):

You could match the first part `sv32[ie][amc]-32[ef][ab]--`  without the trailing space and repeat matching the same pattern preceded by a space in a non capturing group `(?: ..)*`  or use `+` to repeat 1 or more times.

The pattern might be simplified a bit using character classes instead of the non capturing groups.

```
sv32[ie][amc]-?32[ef][ab]--(?: sv32[ie][amc]-?32[ef][ab]--)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrVJhG/1)

**Note** that if you want to match `sv32ia-32ea-- sv32ia32ea-- sv32ia-32ea-- sv32ia32ea--` you could make the hypen optional using `-?32`

You could also make the space optional using `-- ?)+` if you would allow a trailing space.

Comment: Then it wouldn't work if you enter 3 or more strings. In your example you assume only 2 strings are going to be entered by the user. The problem is that we don't know how many times a string is going to be entered by the user. Lets say the user enters "sv32ia-32ea-- sv32ia32ea-- sv32ia-32ea-- sv32ia32ea--" with spaces in between strings except the last one. This example should be acceptable by the regex.

Comment: @santigil If you want that string to be matched you could make the hyphen optional https://regex101.com/r/bvsFIm/1